# Memory mapped files causes low physical memory

Tags: caching, memory, memory-management, memory-mapping

I have a 2GB RAM and running a memory intensive application and going to low available physical memory state and system is not responding to user actions, like opening any application or menu invocation etc.

How do I trigger or tell the system to swap the memory to pagefile and free physical memory?
I'm using Windows XP.

If I run the same application on 4GB RAM machine it is not the case, system response is good. After getting choked of available physical memory system automatically swaps to pagefile and free physical memory, not that bad as 2GB system.

To overcome this problem (on 2GB machine) attempted to use memory mapped files for large dataset which are allocated by application. In this case virtual memory of the application(process) is fine but system cache is high and same problem as above that physical memory is less.

Even though memory mapped file is not mapped to process virtual memory system cache is high. why???!!! :(

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I think you are hinting in your post, the slow response time is probably at least partially due to delays in the system while the OS writes the contents of memory to the pagefile to make room for other processes in physical memory.

The obvious solution (and possibly not practical) is to use less memory in your application. I'll assume that is not an option or at least not a simple option. The alternative is to try to proactively flush data to disk to continually keep available physical memory for other applications to run.  You can find the total memory on the machine with [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589.aspx).  And [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx) will return current information about your own application's memory usage. Since you say you are using a memory mapped file, you may need to account for that in addition.  For example, I believe the `PageFileUsage` information returned from that API will not include information about your own memory mapped file.

If your application is monitoring the usage, you may be able to use [FlushViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366563.aspx) to proactively force data to disk from memory.  There is also an API (EmptyWorkingSet) that I think attempts to write as many dirty pages to disk as possible, but that seems like it would very likely hurt performance of your own application significantly.  Although, it could be useful in a situation where you know your application is going into some kind of idle state.

And, finally, one other API that might be useful is [SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686237.aspx).  You might consider using this API to give a hint on an upper limit for your application's working set size.  This might help preserve more memory for other applications.

*Edit*:  This is another obvious statement, but I forgot to mention it earlier.  It also may not be practical for you, but it sounds like one of the best things you might do considering that you are running into 32-bit limitations is to build your application as 64-bit and run it on a 64-bit OS (and throw a little bit more memory at the machine).

Answer (score 1):

If your data access pattern for using the memory mapped file is sequential, you might get slightly better page recycling by specifying the FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN flag when opening the underlying file.  If your data pattern accesses the mapped file in random order, this won't help.

You should consider decreasing the size of your map view.  That's where all the memory is actually consumed and cached.  Since it appears that you need to handle files that are larger than available contiguous free physical memory, you can probably do a better job of memory management than the virtual memory page swapper since you know more about how you're using the memory than the virtual memory manager does.  If at all possible, try to adjust your design so that you can operate on portions of the large file using a smaller view.

Even if you can't get rid of the need for full random access across the entire range of the underlying file, it might still be beneficial to tear down and recreate the view as needed to move the view to the section of the file that the next operation needs to access.  If your data access patterns tend to cluster around parts of the file before moving on, then you won't need to move the view as often.  You'll take a hit to tear down and recreate the view object, but since tearing down the view also releases all the cached pages associated with the view, it seems likely you'd see a net gain in performance because the smaller view significantly reduces memory pressure and page swapping system wide.  Try setting the size of the view based on a portion of the installed system RAM and move the view around as needed by your file processing.  The larger the view, the less you'll need to move it around, but the more RAM it will consume potentially impacting system responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it sounds like your program needs more than 2GB of working set.

Modern operating systems are designed to use most of the RAM for something at all times, only keeping a fairly small amount free so that it can be immediately handed out to processes that need more. The rest is used to hold memory pages and cached disk blocks that have been used recently; whatever hasn't been used recently is flushed back to disk to replenish the pool of free pages. In short, there isn't *supposed* to be much free physical memory.

The principle difference between using a normal memory allocation and memory mapped a files is where the data gets stored when it must be paged out of memory. It doesn't necessarily have any effect on when the memory will be paged out, and will have little effect on the time it takes to page it out.

The real problem you are seeing is probably not that you have too little free physical memory, but that the paging rate is too high.

My suggestion would be to attempt to reduce the amount of storage needed by your program, and  see if you can increase the locality of reference to reduce the amount of paging needed.